# Why Google Colab only train the 2 first steps of the first epoch (keras)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a 41258 rgb images dataset with this shape: (320, 320, 3). The labels are 42 3d coordinates, so there are 126 labels for each image. The labels shape is (42, 3), but there are reshaped to (-1, 126). The labels are between -1 and 1. And the images are normalized between 0 and 1.

I'm using Google Colab with a GPU, and this happends:

```
Epoch 1/10
  1/103 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0985 - mae: 0.2258 - mse: 0.0985WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.0099s vs `on_train_batch_end` time: 0.0372s). Check your callbacks.
103/103 [==============================] - 4s 39ms/step - loss: 0.0903 - mae: 0.2063 - mse: 0.0903
Epoch 2/10
103/103 [==============================] - 4s 39ms/step - loss: 0.0799 - mae: 0.1872 - mse: 0.0799
Epoch 3/10
103/103 [==============================] - 4s 39ms/step - loss: 0.0800 - mae: 0.1864 - mse: 0.0800
Epoch 4/10
103/103 [==============================] - 4s 39ms/step - loss: 0.0803 - mae: 0.1864 - mse: 0.0803
Epoch 5/10
103/103 [==============================] - 4s 41ms/step - loss: 0.0777 - mae: 0.1807 - mse: 0.0777
Epoch 6/10
103/103 [==============================] - 4s 39ms/step - loss: 0.0774 - mae: 0.1795 - mse: 0.0774
Epoch 7/10
103/103 [==============================] - 4s 40ms/step - loss: 0.0776 - mae: 0.1798 - mse: 0.0776
```

The first epoch only has one step, and then it restarts the epoch.

I tried to use a CPU and all is normal, it only happends when I use GPU.

I can't train all the dataset so I'm doing it in chunks and I have to call fit many times. The problem always occurs in all the first epochs.

Comment: why do you think it has one step and then restarts? you get a warning for the first training sample which cases the output to continue in the next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an error - it's just a tiny formatting change with the output console because of the warning. You can see below the

`1/103 [..............................]` that the rest of the epoch continues in a second line

`103/103 [==============================]`

and then after that the second epoch starts. It's easier to read if you look where the Epoch is announced each time. I see this all the time, it confused me at first too.